# Xamarin HttpClient fails to return from Get requests when Android Phone changes from Wifi to 4G

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a thread that continually does the following `CheckConnection()` method. It works great when the endpoint `Uri` of the `HttpClient` `GetAsync` is available (the endpoint is only reachable when connected to a local wifi ap). If Wifi is then turned off then obviously it isn't available. The `HttpClient` has a timeout of 400ms, and also in the method below I've tried to create the `GetAsync` request with a `CancellationTokenSource` for good measure. It has a TimeSpan of 400ms. Either way if wifi is off the method fails! It just gets stuck. For example if I turn off Wifi while the app is running, the debugger will report that it has entered `CheckConnection` but it gets stuck at the `GetAsync()`

This only happens when there is a data connection available, as in when wifi is disabled it switches to 4G and then gets stuck (I need it to fail fast). This behavior does not occur when changing between WiFi networks, and 4G is turned off.

Any hints as to what I am clearly missing in my logic? Am I right to think this is the source of the bug? In the meantime I will see about how other apps handle switching networks and talking with servers. 
Thanks

The Check Connection Method:

```
public async Task<bool> CheckConnection()
        {

            Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.RestUrl, "work"));
            using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(_FastTimeout)) // _FastTimeout is 400ms
            {
                try
                {
                  HttpResponseMessage response = await connectionCheckclient.GetAsync(uri, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    if ( response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(@"\t connected to server");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(@"\tERROR not connected to server {0}", ex.Message);
                    return false;
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have discovered is that essentially whenever there is a network change you want to create a new `httpclient`. So you need some sort of observer setup or a callback method. Either one can be implemented as interfaces in the main Xamarin project, and then the specific platform projects can implement them, registering them with the Xamarin Assembly dependency framework.

Comment: You can mark this answer as the right answer so that we can help more people with same problem:).